# How can I change the forward movement to follow the player?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to make a vr game and I need to make my own mechanics for certain actions. How can I make it so the forward movement goes forward in the way that the player rigidbody is facing? I am using Vector3 as well for movement

Comment: playerTransform.forward will be the local positive z axis.

Comment: @hijinxbassist So i have to have a local statement?

Comment: It is local as opposed to global.  Vector3.forward is global, transform.forward is local (to that transform).

Comment: thank you very much I will see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

4 common ways to move in Unity

The first: use Vector3.MoveTowards

```
transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(start, end, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

If the interface is moved, it is set to localPosition, and the object is Position.

The second: move using mathematical interpolation

```
   float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
   transform.localPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(start.x, end.x, step),
                Mathf.Lerp(start.y, end.y, step), Mathf.Lerp(start.z, end.z, step));
```

Another is to directly use the interpolation Vector3.lerp(start,end,f), which is more troublesome, because the speed cannot be set, f is a number between [0,1], indicating the proportion of movement, if it is 1, then Finally move to the position of end, if it is 0, it will not move.

Third: use transform.Translate

```
  transform.Translate(Vector3.Normalize(end - start) *
               (Vector3.Distance(start, end) / (time / Time.deltaTime)));
```

Vector3.Normalize represents the direction of movement, and Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, Vector3.zero) / (time/ Time.deltaTime) is the speed of movement.

Fourth: use coroutines

```
 private IEnumerator MoveObject_Time(Vector3 startPos,Vector3 endPos,float time)
 {
     float dur = 0.0f;
     while(dur<=time)
     {
         dur += Time.deltaTime;
         transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, dur / time);
         yield return null;
     }
 }
```

Call this coroutine when you need to move, StartCoroutine(MoveObject_Time(start, enf, time)).

You can also set the speed to move, the code is as follows:

```
 private IEnumerator MoveObject_Speed(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float speed)
 {
     float startTime = Time.time;
     float length = Vector3.Distance(startPos, endPos);
     float frac = 0f;
     while (frac <= 1.0f)
     {
         float dist = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
         frac = dist / length;
         transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, frac);
         yield return null;
     }
}
```

These are the four ways to move，Thank you hope it can help you，The fourth case is ideal for personal testing, but requires a coroutine. In general, you can use the first method to see the effect